# Need some clarification with 8.5.p7 in the C++11 Standard

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization

Paragraph 8.5p7 of the C++11 Standard states:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor
>     (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the
>     initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
>     constructor);
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type
>     without a user-provided constructor, then the object is
>     zero-initialized **and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor
>     is non-trivial, that constructor is called.**
> - if T is an array type,
>     then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is
>     zero-initialized.

I have a problem understanding the characters in bold above. How the additional calling of T's implicit default constructor could alter the zero-initialization, that has just occurred in this case?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a concrete example:

```
class A {
    int a;
public:
    A() : a(1) {}
};

class B {
    int b;
    A c;
};
```

`B` falls in this category - it's a non-union class type without a user-provided constructor.  So if a `B` is value-initialized, it will first be zero-initialized (so both `b` and `c.a` will be set to 0), and then the default constructor will be called (which will call `A`'s constructor and set `c.a` to 1).

By the `as-if` rule, these might be combined into a single step by the optimizer (which will set `b` to 0 and `c.a` to 1), as no-one can ever see the object between the zero initialization and the default constructor.

Comment: It should be noted that VC++ does not correctly implement this. C++98 had different initialization rules and VC++ still implements those. [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/746973/incorrect-c-11-value-initialization-for-type-with-implicitly-declared-but-non-trivial-default-constructor)

Comment: It took me a moment to grok this but, yes, the fact that implicit/defaulted ctors may invoke a non-implicit base ctor is the key. +1 from me

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: non-implicit ctors for members, not a base.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Oops yes that.

Answer (score 5):

`T` may not have its own explicit default constructor, but it may derive from `U` that does, and/or have a member of class type `V` that does.

Comment: Even so, how could that constructor alter the object when it is has been zero-initialized?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "alter the object". To alter something, it first must have a value, which then changes to some other value. A constructor doesn't alter anything, it establishes the initial value.

Comment: Ah - when it says it is zero-initialized, it is not the same thing as `Foo *foo = 0`?

Comment: When what says what is zero-initialzied? The text you highlighted in bold doesn't say that anything is zero-initialized.

Comment: I didn't bold the text (I'm not the asker), but just before the bold text it says "then the object is zero-initialized".

Answer (score 4):

```
struct S {
    int a, b;
    S() : b(10) {}
};

struct T {
  S s;
};

int main() {
    S s{};
    T t{};
}
```

`t` is value initialized and `T` does not have a user-provided constructor. However `T`'s implicitly declared default constructor is not trivial.

`s` is also value initialized but `S` has a user provided constructor.

`s.a` will have an indeterminate value. but `t.s.a` is zero due to the zero initialization that precedes the call of the default constructor. Both `s.b` and `t.s.b` are set to the value 10.